# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre DataSet y DataReader?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, vb.net, .net

En un proyecto que realizo, se implementa en una conexion a la base de datos dataset en todos los casos, sin embargo, mis implementaciones implican usar datareader. Quisiera saber cual es la diferencia entre ambos y en que casos es mejor usar cada uno de ellos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DataReader**

Mantiene una conexión directa con la Base de Datos, quiere decir que tiene que mantener la conexión durante la operación.

Casos en los que seria mas conveniente usar DataReader

Aplicaciones Web,
Grandes Datos,
Manipulando múltiples tablas,
Para un acceso mas rápido a datos,
etc.

**DataSet**

El DataSet a diferencia de el DataReader genera una conexión a la base de datos por un momento, mientras carga los datos para almacenarlos en memoria.
El DataSet pude usarse como objetos para transportarse atravez de capas en camio al DataReader que tiene que pasarse a alguna lista o clase custom.

Casos en los que seria mas conveniente usar DataSet

Aplicaciones de Windows,
Los datos no son demasiado grandes,
Usando una arquitectura desconectada,
Para manipular através de capas,
Almacenamiento en cache,
etc...

En resumen y tomando en cuenta tus requisitos, puedes ocupar el dataset si manipulas tablas de gran envergadura en tus proyectos.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Fuente: [Blog informático](https://helloinformatic.wordpress.com/2013/07/09/dataset-vs-datareader/)

Answer (score 0):

No hay mejor o peor, depende para que lo necesitas y como armes la arquitectura de tu aplicacion, porque si vamos al caso lo mejor seria que pases a `Entity Framework` o algun `ORM`.

Si vas a trabajar con modelos de datos deberias crear clases como ser

```
public class EntityName
{
    public string prop1 {get;set;}
    public string prop2 {get;set;}
}
```

Nota: EntityName es solo un ejemplo que debes adaptar a las tablas de tu modelo de datos

Y en el codigo usas el `reader` para cargar la respuesta en esa clase

```
public List<EntityName> Obtener()
{
    List<EntityName> lista = new List<EntityName>();

    string connstring = "conn string";
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
    {
        cn.Open();

        string query = @"SELECT col1, col2
                        FROM tabla1";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            EntityName item = new EntityName();
            EntityName.prop1 = reader["col1"].ToString();
            EntityName.prop2 = reader["col2"].ToString();

            lista.Add(item);
        }
    }

    return lista;
}
```

Este seria el mejor camino, modelando una `capa de acceso a datos` que retorne entidades